# good place to add recommendation section

Tags: scrolling, error-message, help, recommendations

We are designing an insight section where user can see all the critical status products or campaigns. 
we are providing a "recommended section" at bottom of  the vertical scroll page. 
i have a confusion that user may not know whether there is an helpful section which will guide them to solve the problem caused.

Is there any alternative solution for the placement of the "recommended " section.

My UX structure/hierarchy for this page is

Problem statement > Responsible error details > More in-depth details if there are > Recommendation to solve the problems.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a "product tour": an interactive series of prompts that will guide the user though an interface. These should be used sparingly, as they are purposefully obtrusive. This can be a series of tooltips and/or modal windows.

Examples:

- https://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/indexAuto.html
- https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-tour/index.html#0
- http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aSimpleTour/#
- http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/

This helped me. :)

Comment: This is a good place to start. Good References @invot.